# Most secure way to combine two keys

Tags: encryption

I am developing a application where the idea is to combine two separate keys into a single key. From my research there exists two common ways to do this:

1) Use concatenation of hashes and perhaps hash again
2) Use HMAC

Which would be the more secure approach, and if possible is there any source that could be used to back a specific approach?

Comment: I'm kinda scared to ask but... why do you want to do this?  And what do you hope to achieve by doing so?

Comment: We are given two keys and want to derive a new key that is dependent on both of those keys. It is used in an authentication approach where the entropy of one of the keys is not the best.

Comment: Any one-way function is suitable for use here.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the 2 keys are XOR'ed together to compute the final key